# Undefined offset: 1 using mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])

Tags: php, mysql, offset, datetimeoffset

Good day again guys. APOSTROPHES gettin on my nerve. Please Help guys! I get this error when the RESPO column have an APOSTRPHE word on it "OFFICE'S".

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in xxx:\xxxx\www\ptoms2\reports\view_reports.php on line 14
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in xxx:\xxxx\www\ptoms2\reports\view_reports.php on line 15
```

My line 14 and 15 are this codes which this makes the error lines:

```
$month = date("m", strtotime($data[1]));
$year = date("Y", strtotime($data[1]));
```

To sum up all my view_reports.php are this following:

```
<?php
$respo = $_GET['respo'];

$data = explode("+", ($respo));

$month = date("m", strtotime($data[1]));
$year = date("Y", strtotime($data[1]));

$viewrecord = "SELECT dv.*, dv.respo, (pr.pr_gsis_c + pr.pr_gsis_l) AS deduction FROM tbl_dv dv LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_payroll pr on dv.dv_id = pr.dv_id LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_payroll tpr on tpr.dv_id = dv.dv_id WHERE dv.respo='".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."' && year(dv.date_added)=$year && month(dv.date_added)=$month ";

$run_viewrecord = mysql_query($viewrecord) or die(mysql_error());

{
etc....
```

THank you in advance. I gettin this error for a week and so.. I never imagine that just this APOSTROPHES making this error.. Please Help!

EDIT: This is the actual code I have.. I tried to inject mysql_real_escape_string maybe this is the solution of most APOSTROPHES error. But nothin is working..

This is a DROPDOWN Generated report. In the report.php I choose a RESPO and will gather all RESPO respectively upon the month I selected too.. BUT I have a RESPO that is PROV'L BUDGET OFFICE. WHich the PROV'L contains a APOSTROPHE.. WHEN I Generate the report according to this RESPON I got that error.. and the address is like this:

```
http://xxxxx/xxxxxx/reports/view_reports.php?respo=PROV
```

it should be like this sample without apostrophe:

```
http://xxxxx/xxxxx/reports/view_reports.php?respo=BIPC%2B2014-02-04+10%3A53%3A04
```

Comment: From where is $data getting the data? can you post a var_dump of that variable?

Comment: Remove one of the `AS` in `AS AS deduction`. Plus you may want to change `&&` to `AND`

Comment: Doesn't seem like `$data` is being set anywhere?...

Comment: What do the APOSTROPHES have to do with this error? The error messages aren't for the `mysql_real_escape_string` line.

Comment: Why aren't you using `$respo` in the query?

Comment: @Barmar If I do use $respo I can't generate records on it. I have to get create a explode script to generate the records i need. THis was the Design... From REPORT.PHP I choose a specific Month >> I choose what RESPO I want to view on the report..

Comment: @Barmar What do the APOSTROPHES have to do with this error? The error messages aren't for the mysql_real_escape_string line: yeah! Thats why im confuse about this.. Why I got ang Undefined Offset 1 when all other RESPO word WITHOUT Apostrophes are working. But When the RESPO word contains an Apostrophe I got this confusing error..

Comment: The error has nothing to do with RESPO. It's about `$data[1]`.

Comment: The error means that `$data` doesn't have 2 elements, so there's no `$data[1]`.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I think its that problem.. But how come I can generate RESPO with no problem when the RESPO contains no APOSTROPHE. How to solve this issue.. Please help! I have the screenshot error from report.php >>> view_reports.php link:

Comment: I think you have two unrelated problems. The code you posted doesn't do anything with RESPO. The problem with apostrophes must be somewhere else.

Comment: @Barmar I think NOT. The problem only occur when I select the RESPO "with APOSTROPHE" RESPO like "SAMPLE'S" and generate the report. So it mean's this happens only on the view_report.php. And why is the RESPO working when I selected a RESPO without a APOSTROPHE on it RESPO like "SAMPLE"

Comment: There must be some other code that's causing the problem. The code you posted does nothing with `$_GET['respo']` except assign it to a variable. But it never uses that variable.

Comment: How do you set `$data`? Does it have any dependency on `$respo`?

Comment: @Vertig0 sorry i'll edit the main. $data = explode("+", ($respo));

Comment: @Barmar sorry man I forgot 1 script. after call GET_RESPO. $data = explode("+", ($respo));

Comment: OK. Now I think the problem is in the code that creates the URL. It's not correctly URL-encoding the apostrophe, so `$_GET['respo']` doesn't contain anything after `PROV`.

Comment: As a good practice, you should validate $respo before trying to parse it. If its pattern is not what you expect, the results are unknown.

Comment: What should I do about it?

Comment: @Barmar. if $_GET['respo'] doesn't contain anything after PROV then how can I select it in my dropdown? I can see everything in the RESPO. Except some RESPO have an APOSTROPHE. Just this APOSTROPHE word. How to escape APOSTROPHES..?

Comment: If the sender encodes the URL properly, it should already be escaped, you don't need to do anything in PHP.

Comment: @Barmar. It seem I check my encoders module. I put some escape in respo column on it.. everything is good.. just this happen when im calling the respo with apostrophe.. dammm.. i cant seems to find good solutions anywhere.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use urlencode / decode on the $_GET value passed so it will not truncate the information after the apostrophe. That will resolve your problem.

You would use decode on the code posted above like so:
`$respo = urldecode($_GET['respo']);`

The code you are preparing this statement from would be:
`$variable = urlencode($row['somethinghere']`

Now if it contains an apostrophe it would still send the entire string of data just fine.